# how to save Tokens in retofit in saveprefrence and delete on logout for offline auth android

Tags: android, retrofit

i am new to retrofit i want to be able to save token that would be pesisted when ever a user opens the app and deleted when the user logoutof the apps like what firebase does Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this for your retrofit callback.....

```
 call.enqueue(new Callback<AllResponseData>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<AllResponseData> call, Response<AllResponseData> response) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    ResultBody result = (ResultBody) response.body();
                    if (result.isSuccess()) {
                         PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit().putString("token", result.getToken()).commit();
                         // other stuff over here 
                    } else
                        Log.d("sushildlh",result.getMessage());

                } else
                    Toast.makeText(context, response.message(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<AllResponseData> call, Throwable t) {
                pDialog.dismiss();

            }
        });
```

do this on logout button.....

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit().putString("token", "").commit()
// other stuff over here
```